# aseqdump bash script - I need to disregard multiple instances of a cc event within a short time period

Tags: bash, midi

I have a DIY MIDI controller built around a Teensy. It has toggle switches. Both positions of each switch send a separate control change in MIDI.

I am writing a bash script to run terminal commands using this midi controller, which is connected via USB.

```
   #!/bin/bash

aseqdump -p  "Teensy MIDI" |
{
  read
  read
  while IFS=" ," read src ev1 ev2 ch label1 ctrl_no label2 ctrl_value rest
  do
    case $ctrl_no in
      21) git commit || mousepad ;;

 
    esac
  done
}
```

The issue I am having is that when I flip a toggle switch, multiple events occur. The output of aseqdump is as follows:

```
[ferrum@ferrarius ~]$ aseqdump -p "Teensy MIDI"
Waiting for data. Press Ctrl+C to end.
Source  Event                  Ch  Data
 20:0   Control change          2, controller 21, value 127
 20:0   Control change          2, controller 21, value 0
 20:0   Control change          2, controller 21, value 127
 20:0   Control change          2, controller 21, value 0
 20:0   Control change          2, controller 21, value 127
 20:0   Control change          2, controller 21, value 0
 20:0   Control change          2, controller 21, value 127
 20:0   Control change          2, controller 21, value 0
 20:0   Control change          2, controller 21, value 127
 20:0   Control change          2, controller 21, value 0
 20:0   Control change          2, controller 21, value 127
 20:0   Control change          2, controller 21, value 0
 20:0   Control change          2, controller 21, value 127
```

The multiple instances result from the physical nature of the switch because the number of iterations vary depending on how quickly/slowly I flip it.

This works fine with Ableton, which is what I built the device to be used with. Just having a signal from controller 21 functions correctly no matter what the value is or how many instances of it there are.

However, this is not useful for terminal commands with aseqdump because obviously there are too many instances of the event.

I would like to modify my bash script to disregard these multiple events within a short time period (half a second or so) and output only a single event.

I am a coding novice so your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the real solution here is to learn about [switch debouncing](https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/what-is-switch-bouncing-and-how-to-prevent-it-using-debounce-circuit) and implement that on the Teensy. There's no good reason for it to be delivering multiple events like this for a single switch toggle.

Comment: Yes "switch debouncing" is exactly the phrase I was looking for. I agree, amending the arduino code and compiling a new hex file which includes switch debouncing is the best option, however...      I lost the source code many years ago. Someone else wrote it for me.         Rather than completely recode the MIDI device, I think I'll try to implement switch debouncing in the bash script.

Comment: The `amidi` command has a timeout option. So you could call it in a loop, and react only to the first (or last) command it outputs.